# docker - does it bypass instance-checking limitation like virtual machine

Tags: windows, docker

**QUESTION**

For instance-checking, does docker provide same level of abstraction as a virtual machine?

**BACKGROUND**

I have some software that is license-limited to one instance per machine. I know that if I install **N** virtual machines, I can have **N** instances of this software running on the same machine.

Is the same true of docker? Does it trick this tool's instance-checking mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Docker is a container. It holds all resources required to run an application that can be installed. My understanding is that this extends to all of Userspace, but does not encroach on Kernelspace. Therefore any Linux kernel which supports the included software in a Docker image can run that docker image. The kernel itself is shared between applications, and does not virtualize kernel operations for each docker image (One kernel, many containers).

A VM host may spin up a/many VM(s) that can host a/many Docker image(s), while the host (With the proper supporting packages) may also natively run a/many docker image(s) without a VM running.

Comment: How does this address my question?

Comment: You asked if it provides the same level of abstraction, and I explained it does not. The whole instance checking bit is null due to Docker being entirely user space. A Docker image does not get its own "machine" when it's given resources. I'm not a Docker expert, but I've toyed with your question trying to get around some licensing limits before. Waiting for someone with more experience may give you a more satisfactory answer (I just want to help!)

Comment: Ok but what would an instance check return? Would an app running in one docker container "know" that there's another instance of it in another docker container using the same API it normally uses for instance checking?

Comment: The process itself is still run on the host, so another instance on that same host would be able to check for the process as usual. This also depends on the instance check itself, as it may not be able to deal with dockerized instances (No examples as of yet, but you can always cross your fingers.)